# App Services - Virtual applications and directories

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a front-end application using .NET Core. And Administration part using classic .NET Framework 4.5.

I needed to know if it is possible to host these two applications on the same App service. Administration as a virtual application.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks for your reply.

Yes i did that. But I had a problem to run core and classic next to each other.

I solved this by adding to the web.config of the classic app.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="aspNetCore" /> 
</modules>
```

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, you can deploy the two Web Apps into a single App Service.

You could keep your web sites in separate projects and use the ‘virtual directories and applications’ settings in Azure to publish the two different projects under the same site.

Goto web app -> Settings -> Application Settings -> Virtual applications and directories

In Web Apps, each site and its child applications run in the same application pool. If your site has multiple child applications utilizing multiple application pools, consolidate them to a single application pool with common settings or migrate each application to a separate web app.

You may want to check the blog post [Deploying multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/) for more details.